# How do I hide a div if there's a certain string of text on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, product, hide

I'm trying to only show `class="important"` whenever certain text/products like `'KR-KJSC-MICROBIT'` and `'KR-KJSC-D'` are on the page. When those texts are not on the page then this element should be hidden. Can anyone please assist me with this?

```
<div class="important">SHOW IF CERTAIN PRODUCTS ARE IN THE CART/THANK YOU PAGE</div>
<div class="cart-line-product-info>
    <span class="cart-product-code">
    <a class="product-code">Code: KR0KJSC-MICROBIT</a>
    </span>
    </div>
 <div class="cart-line-product-info>
    <span class="cart-product-code">
    <a class="product-code">Code: KR-KJSC-D</a>
    </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable with the specific words you want to match.
Get html elements.
Iterates throught the product codes (anchors).
If words array includes the textContent of an anchor element, then display the importants elements:

```js
let words = ['KR0KJSC-MICROBIT', 'KR-KJSC-D']

let anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".product-code")
let importants = document.querySelectorAll(".important");

for(let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
  if(words.includes(anchors[i].textContent.replace('Code: ', ''))){
    importants.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'block')
  } else {
    importants.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="important">SHOW IF CERTAIN PRODUCTS ARE IN THE CART/THANK YOU PAGE</div>
  <div class="cart-line-product-info">
    <span class="cart-product-code">
      <a class="product-code">Code: KR0KJSC-MICROBIT</a>
    </span>
  </div>
<div class="cart-line-product-info">
  <span class="cart-product-code">
    <a class="product-code">Code: KR-KJSC-D</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. Not really the best solution but will work if you add the js script at end of page.

```js
const codeElements = document.querySelectorAll(".product-code");
let codes = []
codeElements.forEach( element => codes.push(element.innerHTML))

if(!codes.includes("Code: KR-KJSC-D")) {
document.querySelector(".important").style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<div class="important">SHOW IF CERTAIN PRODUCTS ARE IN THE CART/THANK YOU PAGE</div>
<div class="cart-line-product-info>
    <span class="cart-product-code">
    <a class="product-code">Code: KR0KJSC-MICROBIT</a>
    </span>
    </div>
 <div class="cart-line-product-info>
    <span class="cart-product-code">
    <a class="product-code">Code: KR-KJSC-D</a>
    </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let pageSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML

// regex match for target strings against page source

if(pageSource.match(/KR0KJSC-MICROBIT|KR-KJSC-D/g)){
  $('.important').show()
}
```